# How Apple is assuring that apps compiled against previous SDK's are working under latest iOS releases?

Tags: ios

How Apple is assuring that apps compiled against older baseSDK like for example iOS 9 are working under iOS14 without change in behavior and look?

Does Apple include multiple versions of UIKit, Foundation and other core frameworks in each iOS release?

Answer (score 1):

> Does Apple include multiple versions of UIKit, Foundation and other core frameworks in each iOS release?

Yes and no. Each system version has to be conscious of how things worked previously. That way, an app is not penalized when the new system version suddenly surrounds it.

For example, when we made the transition from iOS 12 to iOS 13, suddenly there was Dark Mode. Also, the default presentation style was `.pageSheet`, partially covering the presented view controller. But it would be terrible if an iOS 12 app suddenly started behaving differently; that could break the app. So if you were compiled against iOS 12, you were "immune" from those changes.

For instance, you were probably counting on your presentations being full screen so that `viewWillAppear` would run in the presenting view controller on dismissal of the presented view. Well, that just went right on working in your older app. But it only kept working as long as you *didn't* recompile for iOS 13. If you recompiled, the app went nuts, as we all remember.

So it's sort of like each new system "emulates" older systems, by taking account of them. But it doesn't really emulate them, because the app usually *looks* like the *new* system. When Apple changed how buttons look, getting rid of the old rounded-rect button style, old apps acquired the new look. When Apple changed how segmented controls look, your old app acquired the new look. And so on.

The trouble is that this doesn't always work perfectly. For example, my iOS 12 app got broken by iOS 13 because iOS 13 draws bar button item background images differently. So in the end I *had* to change the code and recompile for iOS 13, because now my app looked terrible if I didn't change the code. That sort of thing is very insidious and is a big risk for any long-lived app that doesn't get new development when a new system version comes out.

Obviously Apple wants to minimize that kind of breakage. This is their App Store too. They don't want every major update to break half the stuff in the Store! But Apple isn't perfect, so there usually is some kind of breakage in every update.